# how to update @types/node to latest version

Tags: node.js, npm

when I check the command "npm outdated" the output is always "
@types/node 14.18.12" how to update @type/node to the latest version eg now version 17.0.21
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLWVv.png)

Answer (score 2):

you can use

`npm update`

it will update all the outdated packages to the latest version,

`npm update @types/node`

this will update this specific package.

Answer (score 1):

In your `package.json` file there should be an entry for `@types/node`, like:

```json
"@types/node": "^14.18.12",
```

Change that to the new version:

```json
"@types/node": "^17.0.21",
```

Then in the console, cd into the directory that contains `package.json` and run `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this npm command, with the number behind the @ you can set the major version of the package.

```
npm install @types/node@17 --save-dev
```